# recursive use of cursor not allowed. check_same_thread=False указывал в connect. Как использовать check_same_thread?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite3

Как избавится от проблем с многопоточностью в sqlite3 python?
check_same_thread использовал в db = ('main.db', check_same_thread=False)
Помогите!!! Приведите пример работы!!!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Как правильно использовать check_same_thread, и если это не сдержит многопоточность есть другие способы это сделать? Можно пожалуйста пример использования check_same_thread или подробную документацию?

Comment: В документации написано "If set False, the returned connection may be shared across multiple threads. When using multiple threads with the same connection writing operations should be serialized by the user to avoid data corruption." А вообще зачем вам эти сложности, чем вас не устраивают отдельные коннекшены в разных тредах? Приведите больше данных о своём коде и проблемах.